# How do I add a background image that stretches the width of a webpage, using CSS?

Tags: html, css, image, codepen

But it's not that simple. I mean, how do I stretch an image to the width of a webpage, but only takes up 33% of the page (without looking distorted). I want to fill my webpage with 3 different background images that do this.

My question is, do I need to pre-edit the image to a certain length and width, so that they don't look distorted? Or am I just missing something?

I am studying freecodecamp and am trying to create a portfolio with three sections, each image used as a background to that particular section.

I've been researching in Stack Overflow, W3 schools, and tinkering around with different code snippets in codepen.io. I did try resizing the images with a photo editor, and then tried adding them to my page. They still look distorted and weird.

I'm afraid I'm stuck. Would anyone point me to a good resource or offer any insights?

Comment: Can you post what you have to jsfiddle/codepen so we can see what you are working with?

Comment: I'm not sure what jsfiddle is but here is my codepen: https://codepen.io/CeirraWood/pen/MQLjgp                                                                  this is my first draft of the portfolio                                                             these are some drafts I have of tinkering with the photos in a seperate pen https://codepen.io/CeirraWood/pen/YegPQB                   and yeah, I don't know if that helps...?

Comment: I have to make an 'about' section, a 'projects' section, and a 'contact' section. I wanted to use a seperate background image for each section... but when I do width: 100%; and height: 200px; it looks distorted... Should I just edited the three photos together and do background-image: cover; (I was worried that was cheating, since I'm trying to learn/understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

33% of window height?

```
// HTML
<div class="container">
    <div class="img first-background"></div>
    <div class="img second-background"></div>
    <div class="img third-background"></div>
</div>

// CSS
.img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 33vh; // vh means ViewHeight, 33% of your window height
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.first-background{ background-image: url('/a-link-to-your-image.jpg') }
.second-background{ background-image: url('/a-second-link-to-your-image.jpg') }
.third-background{ background-image: url('/a-third-link-to-your-image.jpg') }
```

Comment: This is it! I see you used bootstrap... This is something that I've been avoiding so far but I will focus on learning more about bootstrap over the next week. Thank you for your help...

Comment: Nope! No boostrap. This is just plain CSS. I assume bootstrap would have something similar though, but with their own class names like 'margin-column-2-2' or something weird. Please accept this answer if you found it useful. Thanks! :)

Comment: Oh man, no that is so helpful... I, being extremely new at this, thought if it had <div> that meant bootstrap. Thank you for your help. Also, I clicked the check mark next to your answer to accept it. Thanks again :)